# How to reestablish events after socket timesout on the client side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I see that socket.io seems to close after inactivity and it automatically disconnect and connects again but doesn't use the callback established when I initially connect in the componentdidmount. The disconnect due to the timeout doesn't use the callback that I defined for the disconnect event in the componenet did mount. The disconnect and reconnect of the socket also doesn't seem to be considered a reconnect event. Any suggestions on how to resubscribe to the events that I need upon connection after the disconnect from inactivity?

```
componentDidMount() {

      Socket.on("connect", ()=>{
        console.log("***Successful connection to id ***");

        Socket.emit('subscribe_to_presence',{domain: 'example'});

        Socket.on('presence_status_update',
          (data)=>{
            console.log("User Data", data);
          }
        );

        Socket.on('info',(info)=>{
          console.log("Info",info);
          console.log("Socket is connected?", Socket.socket.connected);

        });



      });



      Socket.on("connect_error", (error)=>{
        console.log("connect error was due to ", error);
      })

      Socket.on("error", (error)=>{
        console.log("General error was due to ", error);
      })

      Socket.on("connection_timeout", ()=>{
        console.log("Connection timeout");
      })

      Socket.on('disconnect', (reason)=>{
        console.log("Reason for disconnect", reason);
      })

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

when using socket to keep the connection open we do ping/pong which tells the other side that they're still there. To close the connection, a simple "close connection" packet is sent.
A good example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/sahat/8364120)